# How do I get rid of global variable for recursive function in this case?

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion

I'm practicing some recursive coding

```
          5
         / \
        1   5
       / \   \
      5   5   5
```

Given a binary tree, count the number of uni-value subtrees.

A Uni-value subtree means all nodes of the subtree have the same value.

This is the code I come up with. However, I have to put the global variable to count the number of uni-value. I can't figure out how to get rid of that. Here's my code.

```
def __init__(self):
    self.count = 0

def countUnivalSubtrees(self, root):
        def traverse(root):
            if not root:
                return {}

            count_left = traverse(root.left)
            count_right = traverse(root.right)

            for k, v in count_right.items():
                if k in count_left:
                    count_left[k] = count_left[k] + v
                else:
                    count_left[k] = v

            count_left[root.val] = count_left.get(root.val, 0) + 1
            if len(count_left.keys()) == 1:
                self.count += 1

            return count_left

        traverse(root)
        return self.count
```

Comment: Wrap `count` into an object and pass to all `traverse` invocations

Comment: you’re not using the return value of `traverse` ?

Comment: @mad.meesh but that would just be the value of the hash?

Comment: according to your code the return value would be `count_left` ... is that a hash? i don’t know

Comment: Does anybody see a global variable? What am I missing here?

Comment: @pstatix I believe by "global variable" they mean "instance variable", i.e. self.count.... anyway, will a leaf node always count as a univalue subtree?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Figured as much. OP: Why not just have a local count variable and pass it? Otherwise, from a class design perspective, having an instance variable that denotes the number of unival subtrees seems perfectly fine and logical. Storing such information as an instance variable would be ideal if you need it frequently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like this?

```py
# returns (count_of_uni_value_subtrees, value)
# assumes nodes have a value other than None
def f(root, val):
  if not root:
    return (0, val)

  (left_count, left_val) = f(root.left, root.val)
  (right_count, right_val) = f(root.right, root.val)

  if left_val == root.val == right_val:
    return (1 + left_count + right_count, root.val)

  else:
    return (left_count + right_count, None)

"""
           f(5)
          /    \
        d(1)   e(5)
       /    \    \
      a(5)  b(5)  c(5)
"""
```

(The empty) children of nodes `a`, `b` and `c` return `(0, 5)` each.
`a`, `b` and `c` each return `(1, 5)`.
The left (empty) child of `e` returns `(0, 5)`
`d` returns `(2, None)`.
`e` returns `(2, 5)`.
`f` returns `(4, None)`.